# Docker container happily uses a used port on the host, how?

Tags: docker, docker-network

I am running Postgres in my host system already. You can see that it has bound to port 5432:

```
$ lsof -i :5432
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres 731 dport    7u  IPv6 0x404077422150a1b1      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres 731 dport    8u  IPv4 0x4040773d52a3bfd9      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
```

After that, I run Postgres using an image like this:

```bash
docker run -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust postgres:14.9
```

When I do so, it comes up happily, even though 5432 is already used. I can't actually connect to it using 5432 from my host, it connects to my host Postgres instead. If this were a normal, host process, startup would fail with some kind of "port in use" error. Why does this not happen with containers?

Build information:

```bash
$ docker --version
Docker version 24.0.6, build ed223bc
```

I'm using Docker Desktop for Mac version: 4.23.0 (120376).

---

**Update**

Alright it turns out I get the behavior I expect if I try to publish ports like this:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust postgres:14.9
```

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 127.0.0.1:5432 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: bind: address already in use.
```

But not like either of these (which I think work identically):

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust postgres:14.9
docker run -p 0.0.0.0:5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust postgres:14.9
```

So I suppose this is less of a Docker networking question and more of a "why don't ports clash when listening on 0.0.0.0 vs 127.0.0.1" question.

Comment: I'm wondering if Postgres treats localhost separate from the local network IP address. They're listed as separate adapters, so it's possible to host on localhost:5432 and not 192.168.0.4:5432. Maybe the docker command without the 'localhost' specifier is adding the port forward to the internal IP and that's okay?

Comment: Hmmm that might be it. Seems like somewhat unexpected behavior, I'd say most people generally think of there being one set of ports per machine, even if that's not really the case.

Comment: are you shure that -p 0.0.0.0:5432:5432 is correct syntaxes and don't work like 
docker run -p 0.0.0.0:5432